# Writing .htaccess Rewrite rules with similar strings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am writing rules in my .htaccess file to configure the URL shown.

In my site I have two pages. Eg. page.php and page_edit.php.

I my .htaccess file I am making the following rules:

```
RewriteRule ^page page.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page/create page_edit.php?editID=1 [NC,L]
```

However, the 2nd rule never gets caught and the page is always directed to page.php (the first rule). I guess this is becuase it is has the string for the first rule ('page') as a substring.

How can I get round this?

Comment: Put the more specific rule (second line) at first place.

Comment: If you are going to have more pages then I would recommend that **page** is a folder.  Then **page** would execute **page/index.php**,  and **page/create** will execute **page/create.php**.  All you need then is one rule to make the default suffix into **.php**.

Answer (score 0):

you can change Rule order, the more specific in top

```
RewriteRule ^page/create page_edit.php?editID=1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page page.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: End-of-string anchors should also be used on the regex, since `^page` also matches `page.php`, which could potentially result in a rewrite loop, if other directives are later added. But `^page` also matches `page<anything>` which could create a duplicate content (and/or spam) issue.